# Is there a way to create a "gallery" of images that updates when a user submits an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, image

I am creating a website that showcases all of my grandfathers pictures. Since I don't have all the photos and there are going to be other people coming and going, I thought it would be neat to have a website that they can submit photos and then view a "database" of them.

Currently, I have a website with InfinityFree and one with github. InfinityFree is great at providing a web platform with good editors, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the server-side of things(i.e how users can submit files and how do I view them). Both have the same code, but I was trying to use node.js which is not available on InfinityFree which is why I temporarily left to move my code to github.

I don't know where to go because no search I have done has yielded anwsers that mean something. Is there a route that I should take to learn how to get then store then show the photos on the website?

Currently this is the code I have. It is the basic backbone of the website. Right now all it does is show the image that the user selected.

`````
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>Here is a site to view and submit photos of _________</p>
    </div>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
        margin: 0;
    }
        
    .header {
        padding: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #663399;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        top: -35px;
    }
            
    .header h1 {
        font-size: 65px;
        margin-top: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    
    .header p {font-size: 25px;}

    .content {padding:20px;}
    </style>
</head>
    
<body>
    <script>
    function handleImageUpload() 
    {
        var image = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("display-image").src = e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    } 
    </script>
    
    <input type="file" onchange="handleImageUpload()" id="upload" multiple />
    <img id="display-image" src="#" alt="your image" />

</body>
</html>````


I am just struggling to see how I have not found a useful video, website, or text discussing how to do this.
It seems as though this should be well-documented and/or easy to implement.
Maybe I am just crazy.
`````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide on [How To upload and retrieve images on mongodb](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/)

then you need a full-stack hosting platform I recommend [Cyclic](https://www.cyclic.sh/) for you ( user-friendly and free)

then any image you upload to your MongoDb will appear on your site
you may also make the upload form a separate page if you wanted this is just to show you the idea of how it may work

another way using firebase [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-image-using-html-and-javascript-in-firebase/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).